# No response from server when angular service gets a redirect

Tags: angularjs, node.js, redirect, express

I have a redirect set up made with Switcheroo that redirect calls from an api server to my local one. The redirect is something like mydomain.com/api/* to localhost:3000/api/. The web app is implemented using angular and all the calls are made by angular services. I don't think angular is involved btw.

The calls are redirected to a Nodejs local server.

When I directly use to browser and I point it to the redirected api url (mydomain.com/api/somedata) I get the correct response. The network panel show me the first call to mydomain.com with a 307 Internal Redirect response, and then the second call to my local server with 200 OK response. Everything works fine and I can see the response in the Response panel of the redirected call..

When I go online I see the exact same two calls but I apparently do not receive any data from the server since the response panel is just showing "The request has no response data available". I know for sure that the redirect is landing to my local server since I see the server logs and when I change the response status the browser receives it.

What can I do? Could be an angular problem since the calls are made by anguar services? I really don't think so but I really don't understand why this happen.

Thanks for your consideration.